# Javascript in nuxt plugins folder - how to use in component?

Tags: plugins, nuxt.js

I have a javascript variable (var testButton) in my Nuxt plugins folder.  I then added the file to my nuxt.config.js plugins.  In my component, I have a Buefy button, and I'm trying to call the script:

```
<b-button @click="testButton">Click Me</b-button>
```

...

```
<script>
export default {
  mounted () {
  this.$testButton()
  }
}
</script>
```

I import the script in my script section and have tried computed and mounted lifecycles.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following things, you must be missing one or more:

#### 1. Your plugin should export a method. That method should receive an 'inject' function and use it to register your 'testButton' function.

So, in your ~/plugins/testButton.js

```
export default (context, inject) => {
    inject('testButton', () => {
        console.log('testButton works!')
    })
}
```

#### 2. You shuold register your plugin correctly in the nuxt.conf.js file

Do it like so:

```
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/testButton.js' },
],
```

#### 3. Call it as '$testButton()' (note that Nuxt will have added a dollar sign to your method's name).

Your '$testButton' method will now be available from anywhere in your nuxt app. You don't have to import it o create any computed property.

```
<b-button @click="$testButton">Click Me</b-button>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>
```